# How call specific action using only attributes without using controller and action name in link CAKEPHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, routes, mapping

I'm trying use only category name to get all products relating to that category from Category controller without mentioning  controller name in link

products is my default controller.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'));
```

i want to get product of any category by this link

```
website.com/category_name
```

while now i'm able to getting in this way

```
website.com/categories/find_products/category_name
```

so kindly suggest me how to use proper mapping/routing to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You router should looks like:

```
Router::connect('/:category_name', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'find_products'));
```

Then in your action you can read your param from:

```
$this->params['category_name'];
```

Important thing is that you have to place this route as last in your `routes.php` file, because it will be catch all requests.

Comment: I used this it is working fine but kindly tell me one thing if i open another controller's action it is not disturbing them , how it recognize either it is action name or category name  i.e i open this link  website.com/products/detail  it is working as well.

Comment: If you want to create route looking similar to this one (`/something`) for other controller/action, that will be problem. Probably you have to create a component for this controllers which will be handle all requests and will be deciding by which controller/action request sholud be handled.